# "Не" - слитно или раздельно. Не()часто

Tags: орфография

Далеко не всегда ваша деятельность является благодарной, (не)часто звучат слова, отражающие ваш вклад... Не слитно или раздельно. Нечасто-редко, значит слитно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Не всегда" пишется раздельно, так как обороты со словами "вовсе не, далеко не , отнюдь не" пишутся раздельно. "Не часто" пишется раздельно, если отрицается, что слова звучат часто, но при этом не утверждается обратное,т.е. что они звучат редко (нельзя заменить синонимом "редко"). "Нечасто" напишем слитно, если утверждается, что слова звучат редко, т.е. можно заменить синонимом.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание слова. Выбор делается по смыслу, а также с учетом структуры предложения, например:

а) Но о вечерних разговорах в маленькой казанской комнатке он теперь вспоминал нечасто, равнодушно. б) Он искренне благодарил за честность, которая теперь не часто проявляется в людях.

Но в приведенном примере раздельное написание предпочтительнее, так как ПОВТОР отрицания (не всегда, не часто), скорее всего, обеспечивает художественную выразительность текста.

Answer (score 0):

> Далеко **не всегда** ваша деятельность является благодарной,
>   **(не)часто** звучат слова, отражающие ваш вклад... Не слитно или раздельно.

Раздельно. Так же, как и ***не всегда.***

**P.S.**

Хотя смысла предложения я не понял.